# Where to find the C/C++ source code invoked by media_jni (libmedia_jni.so) library used by MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I want to understand, how JNI is used to access C/C++ library APIs for MediaPlayer. All I found is [JNI implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp). 
I want to access the C/C++ code which is invoked by MedaiPlayer.cpp JNI to see how video or audio hardware devices getting accessed.

Comment: Just search for the files in your favorite search engine. For example, the corresponding `mediaplayer.cpp` [is here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libmedia/mediaplayer.cpp). Accessing the hardware does not happen at this level though.

Comment: Acronym capitalization; layout.